# How to disable scroll bar nicely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I created this javascript function which disables the scrolling of the page content when the side menu is shown: (like a fb on mobile app)

```
function disableScroll(){
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var left = $(window).scrollLeft();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(this).scrollTop(top).scrollLeft(left);
    });
}
```

However, whenever I try to scroll the side menu, the page content shows the scroll bar moving up and going back to its original position. How do I prevent that from showing cos it looks really ugly.

I tried fixed the scroll position using CSS but it will automatically bring my page to the top which is not what i want. i want it to stay at the position where the user last clicked the button for the side menu to appear.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nazxz/) please? It looks fine to me.

Comment: Hi, it works according to how i want it to be. However, the issue is whenever i use the mouse to scroll down, the scroll bar fidgets, moving down and back the original position.

Comment: What browser? Using Chrome I can't scroll at all. :)

Comment: I tested it on Chrome. Yes I can't scroll at all, but i can see the contents and scroll bar shaking whenever i use the mouse to scroll down. Even though the page stays at the same place, the contents and scroll bar will show some flickering which makes it look very ugly.

Comment: There is no scroll bar for me. Sure we're talking about the same [page](http://jsfiddle.net/nazxz/)?

Comment: hmmm. i have no idea why my scroll bar still appears though it shouldnt

Comment: i tried adding body { overflow: hidden;} to my css but the scroll bar remains. 
i tried adding html { overflow: hidden;} and the scroll bar is gone.

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your own specific browser...

Comment: i tried it on safari and it's the same. the scroll bar is still there.

Comment: No idea, but not sure it's related to CSS.

Comment: i tried $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); to $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden'); and it removes the scroll bar. however, the scroll bar won't come back on when i do this: $('html').css('overflow', 'none');

Comment: Something with your machine is really upside-down, for me it's exactly the opposite behavior. When changing to use `$('window')` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nazxz/1/) then I see the exact problem you describe. Anyway stick with `$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');` and it will work for other people.

Answer (score 1):

You should also set `overflow: hidden` to the `body` element.. Then the scroll bar won't be shown at all. Return it back to the original overflow afterwards.

Comment: hi i used this  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); when i want to disable the scroll but the scroll bar is still shown.

Comment: hmm. i'm not very sure why but it doesn't seem to work on mine. it didnt work when i added body { overflow: hidden;} in my css

Answer (score 0):

**JQUERY**

```
$('body').delegate('#element', 'click', function() {
        $("body").css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });
```

This could maybe fix your problem?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. It only works when i used $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden'). Not sure if it's a good idea to use this way?